# rational approximation of $\pi$, where denominator lies in $[a,b]$

Tags: pi

In a coding competition, I encountered following question:

Given $1\le a,b \le 10^{15}$ , find an integer $Q$ in this range $[a,b]$, such that $P/Q$ is closest to $\pi$. Where $P$ is any suitable integer.

Checking convergence for each integer in the range is computationally inefficient and not accepted by platform.

Comment: Is one allowed to use the knowledge of the first 15 or so digits of pi, to possibly check a certain integer to see if the first digit is correct?

Comment: Yes you are allowed to use the value of pi

Comment: $P=428224593349304$ and $Q=136308121570117$. I used continued fractions of $\pi$, ind of cheating :)

Comment: Why do say find just $Q$? Isn't it find $Q$ and $P$ or is $P$ given to you?

Comment: @Winther I would think that if by some process truly a $Q$ was found such that, for some $P$, $P/Q$ is the best approximation under the limitations given, that finding $P$ wouldn't be all that difficult.

Answer (score 3):

You can go down the [Stern–Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) locating $\pi$, recording the best rational approximations that have denominator in the given range, taking the best approximations found at each step.

Comment: See http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/92symbolic/RationalApprox.java for instance.

Comment: Also Knuth has a good exposition of this in vol. 2 of AoCP.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $\pi$ is a real number between $3$ and $4$, it can be written in the form:
$$\pi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k10^{-k}$$
where $c_k\in\{0,1,2,\dots,9\}$ for every $k=0,1,2,\dots$. We can "cut" the tail of the series, and get that:
$$\pi\approx\sum_{k=0}^{15}c_k10^{-k}$$
or, in other words:
$$\pi\approx c_0+\frac{c_1}{10}+\frac{c_2}{10^2}+\dots+\frac{c_{15}}{10^{15}}=\frac{10^{15}c_0+10^{14}c_1+\dots+c_{15}}{10^{15}}$$
Now, let us assume that $[a,b]$ contains more than one integers - if there's only one integer, the selection of $Q$ is trivial. Let $q_1<q_2<\dots<q_n$ be these integers. Let also 
$$p_i=\left[q_i\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{15}10^{15-k}c_k}{10^{15}}\right]$$
So, we want the closest approximation to $\pi\approx\frac{10^{15}c_0+10^{14}c_1+\dots+c_{15}}{10^{15}}$, hence, we want to minimise the difference - with respect to $i$:
$$\left|\frac{p_i}{q_i}-\frac{10^{15}c_0+10^{14}c_1+\dots+c_{15}}{10^{15}}\right|=\left|\frac{\left[q_i\frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{15}10^{15-k}c_k}{10^{15}}\right]}{q_i}-\frac{10^{15}c_0+10^{14}c_1+\dots+c_{15}}{10^{15}}\right|$$
which is equal to
$$\left|\frac{\left[q_1\sum_{k=0}^{15}c_k10^k\right]-q_i\sum_{k=0}^{15}c_k10^k}{q_i}\right|=\frac{q_i\sum_{k=0}^{15}c_k10^k-\left[q_i\sum_{k=0}^{15}c_k10^k\right]}{q_i}$$
Now, using the known digits of $\pi$, try find the aforementioned minimum (it might be useful to bear in mind that the quantity we need to minimise tends to 0 as $q_n$ grows infinitely).

Comment: For clarity sake - with square brackets, you mean rounding the number in between the brackets?

Comment: Oh, yes, you' re right, I should have mentioned it! Of course (this might need a little bit tweaking - flooring or ceiling - depending on your numerical data).

Answer (score 1):

The best rational approximations will be the convergents of the continued fraction for $\pi.$  We have:

$$\pi = [a_0; a_1,a_2,\ldots]=[3, 7, 15, 1, 292, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 84, 5,\ldots]$$

Then it's easy to compute the convergents by iteration until you hit a denominator bigger than $10^{15}$.  The first two convergents are $3$ and $22/7$.  If the numerators of the convergents are $p_0, p_1, \ldots$ and the denominators are $q_0, q_1, \ldots,$ then the recursion formula is:

$$\frac{p_n}{q_n} = \frac{a_n p_{n-1} + p_{n-2}}{a_n q_{n-1}+q_{n-2}}.$$

So we compute convergents until the denominator is too big:

$$3, \frac{22}{7}, \frac{333}{106}, \frac{355}{113}, \frac{103993}{33102}, \ldots \frac{428224593349304}{136308121570117}, \frac{5706674932067741}{1816491048114374}.$$

So the second last fraction above is the 28th convergent and is the last one smaller than $10^{15}.$

Comment: It is true that the convergents of the continued fractions for $\pi$ are better rational approximations than any of those with smaller denominators, but the [semiconvergents](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semiconvergent) (which interpolate the terms of the convergents) share that property.