# Reduce precision of fraction

Tags: fractions, integers, continued-fractions, machine-precision

Say I have a reduced fraction where the numerator and denominator can only be integers:

$$ \frac{1071283}{28187739} $$

and I want to reduce it more, accepting the lose of precision.

I could just remove an equal numbers of integers from the right:

$$ \frac{107}{2818} $$

However playing around with it shows me that I can easily find a fraction that contains the same number of integers but has lost less precision compared to the original fraction:

$$ \frac{108}{2842} $$

How can I reduce a fraction of integers and lose the minimal amount of precision?

Comment: What you need are simple continued fractions. This gives you the best approximations with limitied size of denominator and numerator.

Comment: $16/421\,$ is even closer. Lookup continued fraction convergents.

Comment: Just play with  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Rationalize%5B0.03800528307715634801358137%2C10%5E%28-6%29%5D

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2540421/589

Comment: A [binary search via Farey mediants](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4122676/242) is quick and easy to remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in comments, use the continued fraction decomposition.
$$\frac{1071283}{28187739} = \frac{1}{26+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{9+
 \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+
 \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{14+\frac{1}{2+
 \frac{1}{3}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}}$$
Halting the decomposition sooner will give you a good approximation, among the fractions with denominators less than the one of the fraction.This gives the approximations
$$\left(\frac{1}{26} , \frac{3}{79}
  , \frac{13}{342} , \frac{16}{421}
  , \frac{157}{4131} , \frac{173}{4552}
  , \frac{676}{17787} , \frac{849}{22339}
  , \frac{1525}{40126},...\right)$$
So for example,
$$\frac{157}{4131} = \frac{1}{26+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{9}}}}}$$

Comment: Let me add that the following maxima command gives the tex code for the big continued fraction: *tex(cfdisrep(cf(1071283/28187739)));*

Answer (score 5):

The [Stern-Brocot Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) gives a sequence of best rational approximations to a number in the sense that if $a/b$ is a rational approximation to $x$ which is not in the sequence, then the sequence contains a closer approximation to $x$ which has a denominator at most equal to $b$.  The Stern-Brocot sequence includes the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) convergents so it is in a sense more general; you have more choices.  In the case of $1071283/28187739$, the sequence consists of $72$ numbers. The Wikipedia article includes an algorithm for generating this sequence.

$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{8}
   ,\frac{1}{9},\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{11},\frac{1}{12},\frac{1}{13},\frac{1}{14},\frac{1}{15
   },\frac{1}{16},\frac{1}{17},\frac{1}{18},\frac{1}{19},\frac{1}{20},\frac{1}{21},\frac{1}{
   22},\frac{1}{23},\frac{1}{24},\frac{1}{25},\frac{1}{26},\frac{1}{27},\frac{2}{53},\frac{3
   }{79},\frac{4}{105},\frac{7}{184},\frac{10}{263},\frac{13}{342},\frac{16}{421},\frac{29}{
   763},\frac{45}{1184},\frac{61}{1605},\frac{77}{2026},\frac{93}{2447},\frac{109}{2868},\frac{125}{3289},\frac{141}{3710},\frac{157}{4131},\frac{173}{4552},\frac{330}{8683},\frac{5
   03}{13235},\frac{676}{17787},\frac{849}{22339},\frac{1525}{40126},\frac{2374}{62465},\frac{3899}{102591},\frac{6273}{165056},\frac{10172}{267647},\frac{16445}{432703},\frac{26617
   }{700350},\frac{36789}{967997},\frac{46961}{1235644},\frac{57133}{1503291},\frac{67305}{1
   770938},\frac{77477}{2038585},\frac{87649}{2306232},\frac{97821}{2573879},\frac{107993}{2
   841526},\frac{118165}{3109173},\frac{128337}{3376820},\frac{138509}{3644467},\frac{148681
   }{3912114},\frac{158853}{4179761},\frac{307534}{8091875},\frac{456215}{12003989},\frac{76
   3749}{20095864},\frac{1071283}{28187739}\right\}
$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4122676/242) for an easy way to generate these approximations via a binary search using Farey mediants (includes a worked example).

Comment: There are several [similarities between the Stern-Brocot tree and the Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree#Relation_to_Farey_sequences), but one distinction worth noting is that the Stern-Brocot tree contains all positive rational numbers, whereas the Farey sequence is limited to the rationals in $[0,1]$.

Comment: The mediants used in the linked algorithm are not restricted to $[0,1]$

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes, I think the algorithm is the same as the one given in the Wikipedia article on Stern-Brocot.

Comment: Probably (didn't check). That's a very old algorithm. I've been emphasizing it in math forums long before Wikipedia existed (early days of sci.math a few decades ago), since it deserves to be much better known.

Comment: For example, [here's a post from 2001](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/gXUeeGVNhuE/m/EW4Nhxpg3wIJ), not the earliest (or best) since the Google Groups Usenet archive doesn't include the early years. Ah for the good ole days...