# if $\frac{p}{q}, \frac{r}{s}$ are positive simplified fractions such that $qr - ps=1$, prove that $\frac{p+r}{q+s}$ is also a simplified fraction

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, alternative-proof

if $\frac{p}{q}, \frac{r}{s}$ are positive simplified fractions such that $qr - ps=1$, prove that $\frac{p+r}{q+s}$  is also a simplified fraction

It's not hard to prove through [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem) actually. Let $(p,q), (r,s)$ be two points on the plane, then $(0,0), (p,q), (r,s), (p+r, q+s)$ formed a parallelogon whose area is $1$. But there is no lattice point within $(0,0), (p,q), (r,s), (p+r, q+s)$, Thus $\frac{p+r}{q+s}$ cannot be further reduced. Otherwise it'd produce a lattice point on the diagnal.

However Pick's theorem is kind of too deep for this. Is there an elementary proof?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3750497) part $\delta p=$ and $\delta q=$, the same reasoning may apply here. See also [wiki/Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ r(q+s)-s(r+p) = rq +rs -rs - ps = qr - ps=1 $$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Show that $$\frac pq <\frac{p+r}{q+s}<\frac rs.$$ Then prove by contradiction.

**Edit**: Alternatively $$\left|\begin{array}{cc}p+r&p\\ q+s&q\end{array}\right|=1,$$ hence $\gcd(p+r,q+s)=1$.