# Question on fractional inequalities

Tags: number-theory, inequality, fractions, integers, continued-fractions

$a,b$ are positive integers. Let $\frac{a}{b}$ be the fraction with the smallest possible denominator $b$ such that $\frac{386}{2019}$ < $\frac{a}{b}$ < $\frac{35}{183}$. Determine the value of $a+b$.

---

I have tried simplifying the inequality, but I am stuck. However, I do know that as $b$ has to be smallest, so does $a$.

Any idea how I should do this question? Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is a wonderful answer by @Batominovski, I'm going to adapt it to this question, in any case see this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750390/why-do-all-integer-solutions-of-frac15750-fracpq-frac227-for-q/3750497#3750497

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the following will help.

We have $$386b+1\leq2019a$$ and $$35b\geq183a+1.$$
We can solve the equation $35b=183a+1,$ which gives $$(a,b)=(13+35k,68+183k),$$ where $k\geq0$ is an integer, which gives a fraction $\frac{13}{68}.$

Easy to see that $\frac{13}{68}$ is not valid.

Now, we can take $k=1$, $k=2$,...

Also, we can solve the equation $386b+1=2019a,$ which gives $$(a,b)=(373+386k,1951+2019k),$$ where $k\geq0$ is integer.

Easy to see that $\frac{373}{1951}$ is valid.

I got that in the first case $k=1$ is valid, which gives $\frac{48}{251}.$

Answer (score 5):

The [continued fraction](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=386%2F2019+as+continued+fraction) of $386/2019$ is $[0; 5, 4, 2, 1, 29]$.

The [continued fraction](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=35%2F183+as+continued+fraction) of $35/183$ is $[0; 5, 4, 2, 1, 2]$.

So the simplest fraction that lies strictly between these numbers has continued fraction $$[0; 5, 4, 2, 1, 3]=\dfrac{48}{251}$$

Comment: Can you explain why we can use continued fractions to get the answer? Thanks.

Comment: @RyanSoh: See [Best rational within an interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Best_rational_within_an_interval) in the Wikipedia article on continued fractions.